# whereHas changing name of the table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Something pretty strange is happening in my relationships in Laravel. Especially with the `whereHas`.

I'm trying to get all the `Lecture` that belongs to a certain `School`. I have the following structure:

`Lecture -> Course -> School`.

I have the following relationships defined:

**Lecture.php**

```
public function course(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Course::class, 'course_id');
}
```

**Course.php**

```
public function school(){
        return $this->belongsTo(School::class, 'school_id');
    }
```

Applying the relationship:

```
$lectures = $lectures->whereHas('course.school', function ($q) use ($request){
                $q->where('id', $request->get('school_id'));
            });
```

**Error**

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'calendarzito.school' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `school` where `id` = 2)
```

Note the `s` missing at `school`.

What have I tried:

Logically first I thought the Model School had a bad name and tried to define manually the name of the table with `protected $table = 'schools'` but still the table name is being changed to `school` and not `schools`.

I tried using Tinker to check if the relationship is correct and it was indeed `Lecture::first()->course->school` and it returns the right school.

Anyone has faced a problem like this before?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the table name to the relationship as well?

`$this->belongsTo(School::class, 'school_id', 'id', 'schools');`

Comment: Oh my god. The error wasn't the relationship but the Validation. I used `exists:school,id` and not `exists:schools,id`. Time for more coffe. Thank you @nakov and sorry for the wated time

Comment: no worries, have fun :)

Comment: what is a school related to a school and a course related to a course? you are making them self referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone for the help but the problem ended up being a validation error and not actually the relationship itself.

```
Validator::validate($request->all(), [
  'school_id' => 'exists:school,id'
])
```

Note the missing `s` at school.

I guess its time for more coffee.